# Should [pythonnet] be a synonym of [python.net]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I saw a question tagged as [pythonnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pythonnet) today, and that seemed like a strange name, so I took a look at the tag page to try and make sure it was relevant. The tag has no wiki information, appears a lot on questions already tagged with [python.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python.net), and, from what I can see, pretty much refers to the same tag.

To restate: should [pythonnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pythonnet) be made a synonym of [python.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python.net)?

Comment: 25 questions in total, 21 have both tags ...

Comment: Are you asking if [python.net] should swallow [pythonnet]?

Comment: @J.Win. based on comment from pnuts below it should be vice-verse: pythonnet should swallow python.net: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369609/should-pythonnet-be-a-synonym-of-python-net#comment601014_369633

Answer (score 19):

I'm one of core developers of pythonnet. Historically since 2003 the library had multiple names such "Python.NET", "pythonnet", "Python for .NET". Hence the duality of the tag names on SO. Ideally pythonnet is a better tag to prevent confusion with unrelated "python.net" website that gets auto-hyperlinked often.
So I think the tags should be made synonyms, which I requested before, but did not have enough votes to get approved.

Comment: Why can't it be a bi-directional synonym?

Comment: @denfromufa that's not how synonyms work. One tag is the synonym, and all questions posted on that tag get the other tag instead. There's no such thing as a bi-directional synonym.

Comment: ok, then I agree with @pnuts